# How to customize legends in Power BI for shapefile?

Tags: powerbi, legend, spatial

I am working with county level shapefile for China and for each county I have some values.
I have uploaded the shapefile in Json format in Power BI like below.
[image: Snip of Power BI]

I wanted to create legend as below map which I have created using QGIS.
[image: QGIS generated Map]

Your suggestion is highly helpful.